# How do I properly calculate the width of a parent div to encapsulate children divs without wrapping

Tags: css

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="margin:auto;width:1090px;">
    <div id="div1" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;">
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:inline-block;width:750px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top;">
    </div>
    <div id="div3" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Given the above example, the parentDiv should be able to contain all it's children divs without wrapping.  If I increase the parent width to 1100px, then all is well, the 3 children divs align within the container and no wrapping, but at 1090px (160+160+750+10+10) the last div (div3) gets pushed below.  The things I've read state that if attributes like border, margin, and padding are not specified then they default to zero, so what in the children is adding the extra hidden something-or-other that requires me to increase the parent div width to greater than the sum of it's children in order not to have the last div wrap under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove "display: inline-block;" and float them.

```
float: left;
```

Why is #div3 pushed downward with "display: inline-block;"? Because inline-block still means inline. It means whitespace. It means, there still will be some vertical space /between/ your divs. Quickly googled this:

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/ , look for "The Enormous Drawback".

Answer (score 1):

bardzusny already gave a good answer on the cause of this which is whitespace, normally caused by having a new line between the children like so:

```
<div>Item</div>
<div>Item</div>
```

Here are 3 ways you can solve this, all side by side. http://jsfiddle.net/4REDJ/

You can float the children, remove the whitespace between the children, or set the parent's font size to zero so the whitespace has no width. I don't like the font solution because it eliminates the children being able to inherit the font size of their parent.

HTML:

```
<p>Default</p>
<div class = "base parent">
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
</div>

<br/>
<p>Floating Children</p>
<div class = "float parent">
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
</div>

<br/>
<p>No Whitespace</p>
<div class = "space parent">
    <div class = "child">Hello</div><div class = "child">Hello</div><div class = "child">Hello</div>
</div>

<br/>
<p>Zero Font Size</p>
<div class = "font parent">
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
    <div class = "child">Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.child {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

.float:after {
    content:'a';
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
}

.float .child {
    float:left;
}

.base .child, .space .child, .font .child {
    display:inline-block;
}

.font {
    font-size:0;
}

.font .child {
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough demonstration of this.  In case others aren't seeing the obvious, the white-space difference is between listing divs like this
    <div></div><div></div><div></div> 

vs lovely like this
    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>